# How to return joined table softdelete data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I got two model "User" and "Post", User hasMany Post, both model are using softdelete.

```
User::join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->withTrashed();
```

this withTrashed() only apply to users table, how can I apply to posts table as well?

I tried

```
->whereNotNull('posts.deleted_at')
```

I also tried

```
 join('posts', function($q){
    $q->on('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
      ->withTrashed();
 })
```

Both also not working

Comment: You should define the relation in user model class. There in the relation query add withTrashed(). 

`$this->hasMany(Post::class)->withTrashed()`

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen any other way without changing existing relation? because sometimes I do not want to retrieve softdelete record

Comment: One is to pass a boolean value to existing relation incase you want to look at deleted records. e.g `$user->posts(true)`. In the relation check if the value is true. Keep default as false. Second is  to define another relation on User model and keep it for all records. So something like `allPosts()`